# How to implement custom apache spark param/parammap in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-2.0

I want to implement a custom spark classifier with custom parameters in **java**. Since I would like it to be compatible with the pipeline architecture, I would like to use the spark param/parammap to implement my own additional parameters.

So far, I'm able to implement custom spark classifiers, but I couldn't figure out the proper way to use param map in java. This is what I got so far, I inherited from the classifier class and set up a specific classifier model. Now I would like the classifier to have another parameter in it's param map, let's say the parameter "n" of type integer with default value = 1.

What would be the most appropiate and conform way to do that? How do I define it and do I need to consider other changes for example in the copy() methods to make sure it is compatible with the other spark functionalities?

```java
public class CustomClassifierTemplate extends Classifier<Vector, CustomClassifierTemplate, CustomClassifierTemplate.CustomClassifierModelTemplate>{

    public class CustomClassifierModelTemplate extends ClassificationModel<Vector,CustomClassifierModelTemplate>{

        @Override
        public String uid() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int numClasses() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Vector predictRaw(Vector arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CustomClassifierModelTemplate copy(ParamMap arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Creates a copy of this instance with the same UID and some extra params.
            CustomClassifierModelTemplate m = new CustomClassifierModelTemplate();
            m.org$apache$spark$ml$param$Params$_setter_$org$apache$spark$ml$param$Params$$paramMap_$eq(arg0);
            return m;
        }   
}

    @Override
    public String uid() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomClassifierTemplate copy(ParamMap arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Creates a copy of this instance with the same UID and some extra params.
        CustomClassifierTemplate c = new CustomClassifierTemplate();
        c.org$apache$spark$ml$param$Params$_setter_$org$apache$spark$ml$param$Params$$paramMap_$eq(arg0);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomClassifierModelTemplate train(Dataset<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```